# No visible @interface for 'BNRItemStore' declares the selector 'deleteImageForKey;'

Tags: objective-c

I'm new to objective C and have been learning with the book "IOS Programming Big Nerd Ranch Guide 4th edition". I keep getting a recurring error and I have been working to resolve it for the last few hours. After researching for a bit, I came here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

"No visible @interface for 'BNRItemStore' declares the selector 'deleteImageForKey;'"

BNRItemStore.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class BNRItem;

@interface BNRItemStore : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSArray *allItems;

// Notice that this is a class method and prefixed with a + instead of a -
+ (instancetype)sharedStore;
- (BNRItem *)createItem;
- (void)removeItem:(BNRItem *)item;

- (void)moveItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)fromIndex
                toIndex:(NSInteger)toIndex;

@end
```

BNRItemStore.m

```
#import "BNRItemStore.h"
#import "BNRItem.h"


@interface BNRItemStore ()

@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *privateItems;

@end

@implementation BNRItemStore

+ (instancetype)sharedStore
{
    static BNRItemStore *sharedStore = nil;

    // Do I need to create a sharedStore?
    if (!sharedStore) {
    sharedStore = [[super allocWithZone:nil] init];
}

    return sharedStore;
}

// If a programmer calls [[BNRItemStore alloc] init], let him
// know the error of his ways
- (instancetype)init
{
    @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:@"Singleton"
                                   reason:@"Use +[BNRItemStore sharedStore]"
                                 userInfo:nil];
    return nil;
}

// Here is the real (secret) initializer 
- (instancetype)initPrivate
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _privateItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSArray *)allItems
{
    return [self.privateItems copy];
}

- (BNRItem *)createItem
{
    BNRItem *item = [BNRItem randomItem];

    [self.privateItems addObject:item];

    return item;
}

- (void)removeItem:(BNRItem *)item
{
    NSString *key = item.itemKey;
    if (key) {
        [[BNRItemStore sharedStore] deleteImageForKey:key];
    }

    [self.privateItems removeObjectIdenticalTo:item];
}

- (void)moveItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)fromIndex
                toIndex:(NSInteger)toIndex
{
    if (fromIndex == toIndex) {
         return;
    }
    // Get pointer to object being moved so you can re-insert it
    BNRItem *item = self.privateItems[fromIndex];

    // Remove item from array
    [self.privateItems removeObjectAtIndex:fromIndex];

    // Insert item in array at new location
    [self.privateItems insertObject:item atIndex:toIndex];
}

@end
```

BNRImageStore.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface BNRImageStore : NSObject

+ (instancetype)sharedStore;

- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image forKey:(NSString *)key;
- (UIImage *)imageForKey:(NSString *)key;
- (void)deleteImageForKey:(NSString *)key;

@end
```

BNRImageStore.m

```
#import "BNRImageStore.h"

@interface BNRImageStore ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *dictionary;

@end

@implementation BNRImageStore

+ (instancetype)sharedStore
{
    static BNRImageStore *sharedStore = nil;

     if (!sharedStore) {
        sharedStore = [[self alloc] initPrivate];
}

    return sharedStore;
}

// No one should call init
- (instancetype)init
{
    @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:@"Singleton"
                                   reason:@"Use +[BNRImageStore sharedStore]"
                                 userInfo:nil];
    return nil;
}

// Secret designated initializer
- (instancetype)initPrivate
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        _dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image forKey:(NSString *)key
{
    self.dictionary[key] = image;
}

- (UIImage *)imageForKey:(NSString *)key
{
    return self.dictionary[key];
}

- (void)deleteImageForKey:(NSString *)key
    {
        if (!key) {
        return;
        }
        [self.dictionary removeObjectForKey:key];
    }

    @end
```

Comment: Where do call this method and do you import the appropriate header files?

Comment: You're calling the method on BNRItemStore but it's declared in BNRImageStore...different class.

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring the method deleteImageForKey in your BNRImageStore class, not in your BNRItemStore.

Check your implementation of removeItem: in BNRItemStore.m

```
- (void)removeItem:(BNRItem *)item
{
    NSString *key = item.itemKey;
    if (key) {
        [[BNRItemStore sharedStore] deleteImageForKey:key];
    }

    [self.privateItems removeObjectIdenticalTo:item];
}
```

I assume you meant to refer to "BNRImageStore" and not BNRItemStore.

Apart from the typo, you should understand that Objective-C objects respond to selectors. Every Objective-C object has an array of selectors that it responds to. When you see the error: "No visible @interface for 'BNRItemStore' declares the selector 'deleteImageForKey;'" you should understand that the compiler does not see the selector you specified as being understood by the class in the error.

Comment: In addition, BNRImageStore.h needs to be imported.

Comment: You might find the forums at http://forums.bignerdranch.com to be very helpful for answers to code presented in the Big Nerd Books.

Comment: I'd suggest editing your comments into your answer rather than expanding in an uneditable and [generally impermanent medium](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19757/) (note also that the asker isn't getting notified of them, though I am because I'm the only commenter here).

Comment: I've implemented the changes and I am now getting two separate errors: "No known class method for selector 'sharedStore'" and "No known instance method for selector 'deleteImageForKey'".

Comment: At this point, the compiler doesn't know how what class or instance methods BNRItemStore implements. We would need to see all of your code to understand, but this most likely has to do with your interface not being included or your mis-typing your class name. Again I would encourage you to head over to the Big Nerd Ranch forums where you can post all of your code. You will find other people going through the same challenges and the immediate problem will most likely be very fresh to other users.